# Как проверять значения в базе данных

Tags: java, spring-boot

Я обрабатываю Post запрос с Json данными, как мне их добавлять в базу данных, чтобы была проверка, которая узнавала, есть ли в базе данных уже этот пользователь или нет, если нет, то создать новую строку, если есть, то для этого пользователя обновить сообщения.

То, что принимаю в запросе: phone, message

Не совсем понимаю как это реализовать.

UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;
    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User requestUserDetails) {
        userRepo.save(requestUserDetails);
        return "The message delivered.";
    }
}
```

User

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ApiTable", schema = "TestApi")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        private String phone;
        private String message;


        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setLastName(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дали [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627946/how-to-check-values-in-a-database-java).

Оказывается, что нас уже всё предусмотрено вот здесь: `userRepo.save(requestUserDetails);`

Save отвечает за сохранение наших данных в базу данных и также, когда он находит по уникальному идентификатору такого же пользователя - для него обновит информацию, но, если такой пользователь не был найден, создастся новая строка в базе данных. Если перейти по ссылке, которую предоставил выше, то там ответили, что можно и предусмотреть вариант, если нам не нравится такой подход и сами хотим меня информацию, то можно использовать вот такой код:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User requestUserDetails) {
        User user = requestUserDetails;

        if(requestUserDetails.getId() != null) {
            Optional<User> userOpt = userRepo.findById(requestUserDetails.getId());
            if (userOpt.isPresent()) {
                user = userOpt.get();
                // пользователь существует... сделать что-нибудь..
            }
        }

        // в конце концов, сохраните пользователя в любом случае (даже, если он существует или нет).
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "The message delivered.";
    }
}
```

Comment: я как понял сейчас идет война **Помогаек** с **Обучалками** и по сути косвенно ты (извини что не на Вы )  на стороне **Помогаек** :3 ничего _мы победим, потому что мы победители_

Comment: Понял, тут всё настолько серьёзно на сайте (а то новичок, не совсем знаю правила), ну да и ладно, пусть воют, моё дело помогать людям :)

Comment: Вот вот я, и про тоже самое говорю :3